# How to add valueChanges on formcontrol added dynamically in formArray in Angular7

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add valuechanges for formcontrol added dynamically in formarray.

This is my .ts file

```
const pwnhAmountControl = <FormArray>this.PWNHAmountForm.controls['formAwnhamountListObject'];

for (let amountObject of this.PWNHAmountData) {
    pwnhAmountControl.push(this.fb.group(
        {
             CustomerId: [amountObject.CustomerId],
             ProductId: [amountObject.ProductId],
             Period: [amountObject.Period],
             SACId: [amountObject.SACId],
             SACName: [amountObject.SACName],
             AccrualFromDate: this.datePipe.transform([amountObject.AccrualFromDate.substring(0, 10)], "MM/dd/yyyy"),
             AccrualAmount: [amountObject.AccrualAmount],
             UserId: ["support"],
             ProductName: [this.fproductname],
             CustomerName: [this.fcustomername]
         }));
}
```

I want to listen for value change on AccrualAmount - please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it inside the loop for each index (control) just like this:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this.PWNHAmountData.length; i++) {
      // build the form 
      pwnhAmountControl.push(this.fb.group(
        {
             CustomerId: [amountObject.CustomerId],
             ProductId: [amountObject.ProductId],
             Period: [amountObject.Period],
             SACId: [amountObject.SACId],
             SACName: [amountObject.SACName],
             AccrualFromDate: 
             this.datePipe.transform([amountObject.AccrualFromDate.substring(0, 10)], 
             "MM/dd/yyyy"),
             AccrualAmount: [amountObject.AccrualAmount],
             UserId: ["support"],
             ProductName: [this.fproductname],
             CustomerName: [this.fcustomername]
         }));
       // listn to values changes
      formArray.at(i).get('AccrualAmount').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        console.log('AccrualAmount',value);
        // Here you can set the value back to zero if it's empty
        let numericValue = +value; // convert from string to number
         if(numericValue == 0){ // see if the result is equal to zero
          formArray.at(i).get('age').setValue(0,{emitEvent: false}); // set it to look like a zero
         // make sure to use {emitEvent: false} so you don't stuck in a loop of setting the value and then triggering the onValuChange event.
        }
      });
     }
```

stackblitz reproduction: (it's a different example but it has the same case).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szxkme-t2aahm?file=app/autocomplete-display-example.ts

You can find the desired code on line 49. Please mark the answer as correct if it did help you.

Comment: Thanks for QUICK solution. Now how i will know which specific AccrualAmount has called? i want to set 0 if its empty.

Comment: You welcome, Why do you need to know which AccrualAmount is called?

Comment: @AmitYadgiri I updated the answer, please check it out.\

Comment: @AmitYadgiri If you want to set a specific AccrualAmount to zero, then you will only need to check the if the index of the control is zero.

Comment: @AmitYadgiri I assumed that you want to set all the AccrualAccount to zero if it's empty, you can customize that the way you like it. 
Please mark it as correct if it solved your issue.

Comment: There will be 8 AccrualAmount textbox if any of its value is changed to blank then I want to set respective AccrualAmount to zero.

Comment: @AmitYadgiri Good, then that should solve your issue, I also updated the stackblitz if you want to try it out on the "age" field.